# Factorisation of fourth degree polynomial in mod p

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $p$ is an odd prime with $p \equiv 1 ( \mod 4)$ then $x^4 + 4$ factors into 4 linear parts $\mod p.$

I was breaking $x^4 + 4 = x^4 + (p-1)x^2 + x^2 + 4 (\mod p)$ then using $p \equiv 1 ( \mod 4)$ we have $ x^4 + 4 = x^4 + (4l)x^2 + x^2 + 4 (\mod p)$ after this I am stuck.

Any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: why not factor $x^4+4$ in the real domain first?

> $$x^4+4=(x^2+2)^2 - 4x^2 = (x^2+2+2x)(x^2+2-2x) \\= ((x+1)^2+1)((x-1)^2+1)$$ Can you start from here?

More hint: $p\equiv 1 \pmod 4 \implies \exists a \text{ such that } a^2 \equiv -1 \pmod p$.

> $$(x+1)^2+1 \equiv (x+1)^2-a^2 \pmod p\\ (x-1)^2+1 \equiv (x-1)^2-a^2 \pmod p$$ Can you end it now?

Comment: Yes. It's clear now. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* If $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$, then there is $j \in \mathbb Z$ such that $j^2 \equiv -1 \bmod p$.
Also, the complex roots of $x^4+4$ are $\pm 1 \pm i$.

Comment: Yeah we have that. After that ?

Comment: @hiren_garai, see my edited answer